# DolphinDB: How to cancel all subscriptions of a specified stream table at once?

Tags: streaming, subscription, dolphindb

I subscribe to a stream table with Grafana, but I don’t know the actionName of this subscription. How to cancel all subscriptions of this table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `getStreamingStat` to get the subscription status. Then cancel all subscriptions of a specified table at once using a user-defined function, as shown in the following script:

```
def unsubscribeAll(tabName) {
    t = getStreamingStat().pubTables

    for(row in t){
        if(string(row.actions).startsWith("[")) {
            actions = split(substr(row.actions, 1, strlen(row.actions)-2), ",")
        } else {
            actions = [].append!(row.actions)
        }

        for(action in actions){
            unsubscribeTable(tableName=tabName, actionName=action)
        }
    }
}
```